# INVALID_SESSION_ID when calling Apex class with custom button

Tags: apex, rest-api, custom-button, page-layout, account

I have an Apex class that I have exposed as a REST endpoint located at `/services/apexrest/ReopenAccount/*`. When I call it through Workbench, it works fine, so I created a Detail Page Button so that I can call it from my `Account` page layout.

The button url is `/services/apexrest/ReopenAccount/accountId={!CASESAFEID(Account.Id)}` in order to pass it to my Apex class, which is set up like this:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/ReopenAccount/*')
global with sharing class ClosedAccountMethods {
    @HttpGet
    global static void Reopen() {
        RestRequest request = RestContext.request;
        string accId = request.requestURI.substring(request.requestURI.indexOf('accountId=')+10);
        //Do something with the account Id
    }
}
```

However, when I click the button from the account page, I get redirected to an error page that says:

```
<Errors>
    <Error>
        <errorCode>INVALID_SESSION_ID</errorCode>
        <message>Session expired or invalid</message>
    </Error>
</Errors>
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there some sort of authentication that I need to do?

Thank you!

Comment: Hey Douglas, have you found any solution for this issue? Exactly facing the same thing. I even tried to pass in the SessionId={!API.Session_ID} in the URLFOR but no success.

Answer (score 0):

Yes authentication will be required. This blog explains how to do it:
https://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/call-salesforce-rest-api-from-apex/

Answer (score 0):

Anything under the `/services` resource in Salesforce requires a valid Session Id, with the exception of unauthenticated Site.com pages, which will run with a Guest User Session Id. In other words, you can't just point your web browser to a URL like [https://something.my.force.com/services/apexrest/ReopenAccount/accountId={!$CASESAFEID(Account.Id)}](https://something.my.force.com/services/apexrest/ReopenAccount/accountId=%7B!$CASESAFEID(Account.Id)%7D). Even if this worked, you'd be left on a page with some kind of plain JSON response instead of returning to a useful page somewhere in Salesforce.

First of all, that URL isn't partiularly "REST-ful." The AccountId should be either supplied directly in the URL:

[https://something.my.force.com/services/apexrest/ReopenAccount/{!$CASESAFEID(Account.Id)}](https://something.my.force.com/services/apexrest/ReopenAccount/%7B!$CASESAFEID(Account.Id)%7D)

Or preferably, as a query string parameter:

[https://something.my.force.com/services/apexrest/ReopenAccount/?accountId={!$CASESAFEID(Account.Id)}](https://something.my.force.com/services/apexrest/ReopenAccount/?accountId=%7B!$CASESAFEID(Account.Id)%7D)

Either way, you still need a Session Id. That means you're going to have to use JavaScript and call the page directly. Change your Button to a JavaScript onclick handler, and use code like the following:

```
try {
  fetch(
    '{!$Site.BaseUrl}/services/apexrest/ReopenAccount', 
    {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer {!$Api.Session_Id}',
      }
    }
  ).then((result) => {
    // Do something with the return value here
    window.top.location.reload();
  });
} catch(e) {
  alert(e.message?.body || e.message || e);
}
```

Note that this only applies to the Classic UI. If you're in Lightning, just create a [Lightning Quick Component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_quick_actions_headless) and use [notifyRecordUpdateAvailable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_notify_record_update) to refresh the Lightning Data Service cache when you're done.